# Is this series divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n} - \left \lfloor {\sqrt {n}} \right \rfloor} {n} $$ divergent?
I have tried both ratio test and root test, but they are definitely to weak to tackle this problem, I can't use integral test for this.
I figured out that you can express this series as $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{2k} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+i}} - \frac{k}{k^2+i}\right) $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N^2} \frac{\sqrt{n} - \left \lfloor {\sqrt {n}} \right \rfloor} {n}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{n=(k-1)^2+1}^{k^2} \frac{\sqrt{n} - \left \lfloor {\sqrt {n}} \right \rfloor} {n}=\sum_{k=2}^{N}\left(-\frac1{k^2}+\sum_{n=(k-1)^2+1}^{k^2} \frac{\sqrt{n} -k+1} {n}\right)$$

and

$$\sum_{k=2}^{N}\left(\sum_{n=(k-1)^2+1}^{k^2} \frac{\sqrt{n} -k+1} {n}\right)\ge \sum_{k=2}^{N}\left(
 \frac{2k-1} {k^2}\right)$$

which diverges.

Comment: I don't get where this inequality has come from. I understand the choice of the denominator, but I can't figure the numerator

Comment: In the inner sum we have $2k-1$ terms and $1/k^2$bis the smallest.

Comment: Why the downvote? Something wrong to fix? Let me know in case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a short intuitive answer, note that fractional part of $\sqrt(n)$ are equidistributed $\mod 1$. Note that for each $n$ such that integral part of $sqrt(n)$ is $k$, there is about $k/2 +o(1)$ corresponding numbers whose square root has integral part $k$ and fractional part about $1/2$, hence you can convert the sum to about half of harmonic series. which diverges.

Comment: I suspect your $o(1)$ may actually be $1$

Comment: Yeah, that does make sense, but I need something more formal, but at least I am now sure that this converges. Thanks for reply nonetheless

Comment: +1 I like this reasoning with (pseudo)random numbers.